# Исключение : Необработанное исключение: System.FormatException: Входная строка имела неверный формат

Tags: c#

Вот код при компиляции выходит ошибка не могу решить никак.

```
var inputArg1 = File.ReadAllLines(args[0], Encoding.Default).ToArray();
var inputArg2 = File.ReadAllLines(args[1], Encoding.Default).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < inputArg1.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(inputArg1.ToString()));
}
Console.WriteLine("Второй файл ");
for (int j = 0; j < inputArg2.Length; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(inputArg2.ToString()));
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так вы имя файла в число пытаетесь перевести

Comment: В файле просто по одному числу на каждой строке ? вы хоть покажи что там конвертируется. Возможно там в конце каждой строки \r\n (перевод строки) и они не дают выполнить конвертацию

Comment: Прошу прощения, не указал, что отражено было во входных файлах. Там было 1 1 на одной сторке и после добавления индекса к моим параметрам, удаления пробела между 1 и 1 и переноса 1 на новую строку все заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К элементам массива надо обращаться по индексу.

```cs
string[] inputArg1 = File.ReadAllLines(args[0]);
string[] inputArg2 = File.ReadAllLines(args[1]);

for (int i = 0; i < inputArg1.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse(inputArg1[i], out int number) ? number : $"Ошибка в строке {i}: {inputArg1[i]}");
}
Console.WriteLine("Второй файл");
for (int j = 0; j < inputArg2.Length; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse(inputArg2[j], out int number) ? number : $"Ошибка в строке {j}: {inputArg2[j]}");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```